# os.path.join returning Errno22 in Enthought/Python

Tags: python, path, numpy, errno, enthought

I'm working with a fairly complex Enthought/Python program that is returning this error:

```
File "C:\Users\riddle\Desktop\FCI2\src\equation.py", line 41, in main
fci_data = np.load(os.path.join(local_data_path, "fci_data.npy"))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 329, in load
fid = open(file, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\white\\Desktop\
\FCI2New\\data\\fci_data.npy'
```

With respect to this:

```
    fci_data = np.load(os.path.join(local_data_path, "fci_data.npy"))
    fci_data = fci_data.replace("'\\','/'")
```

The additional slashes are particularly puzzling me. local_data_path is global and is defined like so:

```
local_data_path = static.base_data_path
base_data_path = "C:\Documents and Settings\white\Desktop\FCI2New\data" (from the        static module)
```

Anyone have an idea what might be the issue here? 'rb' should be the correct mode for fci_data. Please forgive any errors or obvious questions, I'm a beginner.

Anne

Comment: Maybe something funny happens due to the magic conversion of "C:\Documents and Settings" to "C:\Users". Does it work if you directly specify base_data_path = r"C:\Users\...."? Also, as defined, base_data_path either needs its backslashes to be escaped, or to use a raw string (as I have done with the letter r, which looks so much nicer). And why do you need to replace you backslashes with forward slashes?

Comment: The doubling of backslashes in the error message is because it is showing `repr(the_path)`. What IS surprising is the SINGLE backslash before "white" ... is this from a copy/paste or have you been typing this manually??

Answer (score 0):

try first to normalize the path :

```
local_data_path = os.path.normpath(local_data_path)
```